# How to switch page in a table with scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to get the table from this site: https://www.burgrieden.de/index.php?id=77
I managed to get the first site, but I can not access the other 4 pages.
The only explanations and examples I can find are with a direct link to the other site or an easy URL manipulation.
I have tried to inspect the button and see what happens in the network logger when pressing it.
But nothing worked.
How can i get to the next page with scrapy?

Here is what I have so far:

```
from abc import ABC
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import re
from datetime import datetime


class TrashSpider(scrapy.Spider, ABC):
    name = "Trasher"
    start_urls = ['https://www.burgrieden.de/index.php?id=77']

    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        for row in response.xpath('//*[@class="contenttable"]//tr')[1:]:
            d = row.xpath('td//text()')[0].extract()
            match = re.search(r'\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}', d)
            date = datetime.strptime(match.group(), '%d.%m.%Y').date()
            entry = {
                'date': date,
                'type': row.xpath('td//text()')[2].extract()
            }


process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(TrashSpider)
process.start()
```

[Inspector Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZFO1.png)

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone who is having the same question. I figured it out.
It is a button which triggers a POST request. To trigger this request with scrapy you have to define the request-headers and the request-form.
Both can be found using your browsers networkanalyzer:

[image]

On the left side you can see the method used to request the site. The marked entry says POST.
Now we need to get the headers which can be found in the right bottom field and put them in a dictionary in our spider_class.
Make sure to **ignore the content-length**. Just leave it blank or do not add it in your dictionary at all, because scrapy will send an own content-length and when more than one gets send, the side will block your request. Code 400 instead of 200.

The form data can be found at least in firefox under the request tab:

[image]

Here we need the whole line right as it is and put in a variable to use it in the actual request.
This is how it is supposed to look:

```
# request-header for POST request
headers = {
    'Host': 'www.burgrieden.de',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:86.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/86.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    # 'Content-Length': '219',
    'Origin': 'https://www.burgrieden.de',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': 'https://www.burgrieden.de/index.php?id=77',
    'Cookie': 'style=normal.css',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
}

# POST request form data for every table page
form_data_p1 = 'publish%5BbtnStart%5D=+%7C%3C+&publish%5Bstart%5D=40&publish%5BdayFrom%5D=20&publish%5BmonthFrom%5D=03&publish%5ByearFrom%5D=2021&publish%5BdayTo%5D=&publish%5BmonthTo%5D=&publish%5ByearTo%5D=&publish%5Bfulltext%5D=&id=77'
```

To make sure it works you have to disable cookies like this:
Just put it in your custom spider class

```
# custom scraper settings
custom_settings = {
    # pass cookies along with headers
    'COOKIES_ENABLED': False
}
```

For the actual request you have to use the start_requests() method.

```
# crawler's entry point
def start_requests(self):
    # make HTTP POST request
    # page 1
    yield scrapy.Request(
        url=self.start_url,
        method='POST',
        headers=self.headers,
        body=self.form_data_p1,
        callback=self.parse
    )
```

Now you can parse the response with your normal parse() method.
If you get any problems try leaving the host in your headers blank or delete it.

Here is the whole class code:

```
class TrashSpider(scrapy.Spider, ABC):
name = "Trasher"
start_url = "https://www.burgrieden.de/index.php?id=77"

# request-header for POST request
headers = {
    'Host': 'www.burgrieden.de',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:86.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/86.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    # 'Content-Length': '219',
    'Origin': 'https://www.burgrieden.de',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': 'https://www.burgrieden.de/index.php?id=77',
    'Cookie': 'style=normal.css',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
}

# POST request form data for every table page
form_data_p1 = 'publish%5BbtnStart%5D=+%7C%3C+&publish%5Bstart%5D=40&publish%5BdayFrom%5D=20&publish%5BmonthFrom%5D=03&publish%5ByearFrom%5D=2021&publish%5BdayTo%5D=&publish%5BmonthTo%5D=&publish%5ByearTo%5D=&publish%5Bfulltext%5D=&id=77'
form_data_p2 = 'publish%5BbtnNext%5D=+%3E%3E+&publish%5Bstart%5D=0&publish%5BdayFrom%5D=20&publish%5BmonthFrom%5D=03&publish%5ByearFrom%5D=2021&publish%5BdayTo%5D=&publish%5BmonthTo%5D=&publish%5ByearTo%5D=&publish%5Bfulltext%5D=&id=77'
form_data_p3 = 'publish%5BbtnNext%5D=+%3E%3E+&publish%5Bstart%5D=10&publish%5BdayFrom%5D=20&publish%5BmonthFrom%5D=03&publish%5ByearFrom%5D=2021&publish%5BdayTo%5D=&publish%5BmonthTo%5D=&publish%5ByearTo%5D=&publish%5Bfulltext%5D=&id=77'
form_data_p4 = 'publish%5BbtnNext%5D=+%3E%3E+&publish%5Bstart%5D=20&publish%5BdayFrom%5D=20&publish%5BmonthFrom%5D=03&publish%5ByearFrom%5D=2021&publish%5BdayTo%5D=&publish%5BmonthTo%5D=&publish%5ByearTo%5D=&publish%5Bfulltext%5D=&id=77'
form_data_p5 = 'publish%5BbtnNext%5D=+%3E%3E+&publish%5Bstart%5D=30&publish%5BdayFrom%5D=20&publish%5BmonthFrom%5D=03&publish%5ByearFrom%5D=2021&publish%5BdayTo%5D=&publish%5BmonthTo%5D=&publish%5ByearTo%5D=&publish%5Bfulltext%5D=&id=77'


# custom scraper settings
custom_settings = {
    # pass cookies along with headers
    'COOKIES_ENABLED': False
}

entrys_crawled = []

# crawler's entry point
def start_requests(self):
    # make HTTP POST request to burgrieden
    # page 1
    yield scrapy.Request(
        url=self.start_url,
        method='POST',
        headers=self.headers,
        body=self.form_data_p1,
        callback=self.parse
    )

    # page 2
    yield scrapy.Request(
        url=self.start_url,
        method='POST',
        headers=self.headers,
        body=self.form_data_p2,
        callback=self.parse
    )

    # page 3
    yield scrapy.Request(
        url=self.start_url,
        method='POST',
        headers=self.headers,
        body=self.form_data_p3,
        callback=self.parse
    )

    # page 4
    yield scrapy.Request(
        url=self.start_url,
        method='POST',
        headers=self.headers,
        body=self.form_data_p4,
        callback=self.parse
    )

    #page 5
    yield scrapy.Request(
        url=self.start_url,
        method='POST',
        headers=self.headers,
        body=self.form_data_p5,
        callback=self.parse
    )

# parse date and description from table "contenttable",
# extract date from shitty formatted text and store in dictionary entry as datetime
def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
    for row in response.xpath('//*[@class="contenttable"]//tr')[1:]:
        d = row.xpath('td//text()')[0].extract()
        match = re.search(r'\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}', d)
        entry = {
            'date': datetime.strptime(match.group(), '%d.%m.%Y').date(),
            'type': row.xpath('td//text()')[2].extract()
        }
        self.entrys_crawled.append(entry)
```

There is propably a better way for processing more than one post-request, but it worked for me. If someone wants to improve it and send it to me, please feel free to do so.

For everyone who is wondering about the entrys_crawled. I processed it into an .ics file in scrapys close() method.